# Noise on a Curve with python

Tags: python, bezier-curves

I would like to apply noise to a curve where this noise should behave like a noise texture does in the geometry nodes.
In this script a small noise has been added to the curve.

[image]

This is not a problem with the random module. But how can I make a noise that spreads the curve over further distances, like the blue line I painted over the curve?
Maybe it works with the noise functions from mathutils module. But I don't understand how to apply them.

Here is my script:

```
import bpy, random

myCurve = bpy.data.curves.new("MyCurve",'CURVE')
# make some settings to the container
myCurve.dimensions = '3D'                                       
myCurve.resolution_u = 1
myCurve.use_fill_caps = True
myCurve.fill_mode = 'FULL'
myCurve.bevel_depth = 0.2
myCurve.bevel_resolution = 0

Spline_Coords = []
X,Y,Z = (0,0,0)

# Create Coordinates
for i in range(100):
    X = 0
    Y = 0
    X += random.uniform(0,0.4)
    Y += random.uniform(0,0.4)
    Z += 0.1
    
    Spline_Coords.append((X,Y,Z))

# Create Bezline
Bezline = myCurve.splines.new('BEZIER') #Create a spline (with one Point already)
Bezline.bezier_points.add(len(Spline_Coords)-1) # add Points without Coordinates (-1 to not close the curve) 
for number, coord in enumerate(Spline_Coords): # give the Points the Coordinates
    x,y,z = coord
    Bezline.bezier_points[number].co = (x, y, z)   

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyCurve", myCurve)

bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(obj)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can get closer to what you want using some of the [noise](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/mathutils.noise.html) functions from mathutils.

for instance:

```
import bpy, random
from mathutils import noise, Vector

myCurve = bpy.data.curves.new("MyCurve",'CURVE')
# make some settings to the container
myCurve.dimensions = '3D'                                       
myCurve.resolution_u = 1
myCurve.use_fill_caps = True
myCurve.fill_mode = 'FULL'
myCurve.bevel_depth = 0.2
myCurve.bevel_resolution = 0

Spline_Coords = []
X,Y,Z = (0,0,0)

# Create Coordinates
# Just added a noise.hetero_terrain, and use that 
# value for the y value, I basically picked the other 
# values at random from values that seemed reasonable
for i in range(100):
    Z += 0.1
    loc = Vector((X,Y,Z))
    H = 1.0
    lacunarity = 1.2
    octaves = 3
    offset = .5
    n = noise.hetero_terrain(loc, H, lacunarity, octaves, offset)
    Spline_Coords.append((X, n, Z))
    
    

# Create Bezline
Bezline = myCurve.splines.new('BEZIER') #Create a spline (with one Point already)
Bezline.bezier_points.add(len(Spline_Coords)-1) # add Points without Coordinates (-1 to not close the curve) 
for number, coord in enumerate(Spline_Coords): # give the Points the Coordinates
    x,y,z = coord
    Bezline.bezier_points[number].co = (x, y, z)   

obj = bpy.data.objects.new("MyCurve", myCurve)

bpy.data.collections['Collection'].objects.link(obj)
```

Which got this result.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your tip!
I have now played around for about 2 hours with the various noise functions, but unfortunately the size of the noise can not be set correctly. What I want is just one or 2 random big curves.